# How to convert the dict to list of list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, series

I want the data looks like this:

```
[['2017-01-01', 14861],
 ['2017-01-02', 12956],
 ['2017-01-03', 14206],
 ['2017-01-04', 1453],
 ['2017-01-05', 21297],
 ['2017-01-06', 13078],
 ['2017-01-07', 7509]]
```

However, my data is a series transofrmed from a column of DataFrame

```
tm = dfx['time_by_m']
s = tm.value_counts()
m = s.to_dict()
```

it looks like this:

```
{' 2001-07': 74,
 ' 2000-04': 57,
 ' 1999-12': 52,
 ' 2001-02': 50,
 ' 1999-02': 44}
```

How to convert the dict to the list of list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution. Iterate through the dict and append to the returning list. Let me know if its helpful.

```
ans = []
for key, val in m.items():
    ans.append([key, val])
print ans
```